# Odd JS console error in firefox web developer (about chrome though...?)

Tags: javascript, console

```
Error: [Exception... "'JavaScript component does not have a method named: "handleEvent"' when calling method: [nsIDOMEventListener::handleEvent]"  nsresult: "0x80570030 (NS_ERROR_XPC_JSOBJECT_HAS_NO_FUNCTION_NAMED)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://global/content/bindings/popup.xml :: hidePopup :: line 108"  data: no]
Source File: chrome://global/content/bindings/popup.xml
Line: 108
```

Anyone ever seen this?  Any idea where it could be coming from?

Comment: I'm getting a lot of these lately: Error: p.onStatusChange is not a function
Source File: chrome://browser/content/tabbrowser.xml
Line: 546, I guess I need to upgrade from 3.6...

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=449038

Comment: The word "chrome" is a XUL term and has nothing (directly, anyway) to do with Chrome or Chromium.

Comment: _Mozilla-programmers sometimes refer to XUL applications running locally as chrome_
References: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUL, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Chrome

Comment: I had a similar issue triggered by some jQuery event which failed due to an AJAX refresh of the bound element. There must be multiple possible scenarios which cause this error (Firefox extensions, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Don't upgrade. With an upgrade from Mozilla 4.6 you may see this line below before it crashes:

```
Script: chrome://browser/content/tabbrowser.xml:1636
```